# Sqlalchemy, column_property collection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is model

```
class Trade(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'trade'
    ***
    original_price = Column(FLOAT)
    left_volume = Column(FLOAT)
    result_right_volume = Column(FLOAT)
    original_right_volume = column_property(original_price * left_volume)
    all_prices = Bundle(None,original_price, result_right_volume, exec_price, original_right_volume)
```

Then I want to use it in query

```
Trade.query(...., Trade.app_prices)
```

Nor orm.Bundle, nor orm.composite dont work with column_property.
Motivation - yes, I can list all fields in query, but I have much queries and, for convenience, want use this way. Tried to use ClauseList and ColumnsList, didn't reach success. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I can deal with it by writing this way:

```
class Trade(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'trade'
    ***
    original_price = Column(FLOAT)
    left_volume = Column(FLOAT)
    result_right_volume = Column(FLOAT)
    original_right_volume = column_property(original_price * left_volume)
Trade.all_prices = Bundle(None, Trade.original_price, Trade.result_right_volume, Trade.exec_price, Trade.original_right_volume)
```

Looks like problem is with sqlalchemy 'magic' and their metaclasses. Column property not ready when it processing bundle.